# Classic Set theory Pp8-9

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

This is similar but still distinct from a question asked by someone else a few months ago. In "Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study" page 8 The concept of a Dedekind cut as a partition on Q is introduced, where R is the set of all such partitions. On page 9 however he focuses on a Dedekind L set. He gives a 3 part definition:

(i) r a proper non empty subset of Q

(ii) r ‘closed to the left’, where if q E r and p<q then p E r

(iii) r has no maximum element

He then states that a real number is a Dedekind Left set.

Here are my 2 questions:

1. in (ii) why not r ‘open to the left’ as it seems to be defined as r
   extending infinitely to the left, I.e. for all p<q, q E r
2. How can a single real number be defined as a set with infinite elements? My understanding is that the (yet unstated) partition bounding the Left set on the Right is a  real number as in a Dedekind cut dividing Q into L & R sets is a real number. What am I confusing here?

Comment: "closed" does not mean "closed interval" because if we write it as interval it will be like $\mathsf r = (-\infty, ?)$ but is "closed" in the sense that contains every *rational* such that...

Comment: We start from the set of rationals and we have to "extend" them in order to add to the (set of) rationals the "points" corresponding to entity that are not rationals, like e.g. $\sqrt 2$. Several ways to do it: Cauchy sequences, that means that a *real* is a sequence, i.e. a set of rationals and Dedekind cuts, where again a real is a set of rationals.

Comment: The intuition is in the word "cut"; we cut the continuous line into two portions (that must be disjoint): the left part and the right part. We can use the partition itself or - due to the fact that the right part is the complement of the left one - use the left part only.

Comment: Thanks Mauro, Ok, “closed” makes sense now,. But I still don’t understand how a L set is a single real?, The partition between the disjoint R and L sets marking a real on the number line seems clear , but how is a set to the Left of the partition, with infinite rationals, itself a  real number?

Comment: Do you know the machinery of construction of number systems? How a pair of integers is a rational? Because we define it so. the same for real: a real is "constructed" as a set of rational. The key-point is that this "strange" new entity called "Dedekind cut" satisfies all axioms for real (to be proved). Apply the [Duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) to mathematics: "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it [...] is a duck.

Comment: Or stated another way if “We can use the partition itself or - due to the fact that the right part is the complement of the left one - use the left part only.”, then the  partition and the left set are entirely different mathematical objects, how can both identify the same real? Moreover the elements of the L set are rationals. How is a set of rationals = a single real?

Comment: I am only going by his reasoning, as stated early in the book with no further backround. there is source of confusion here.

Comment: Maybe you can re-read the introductory explanation at page 8.

Comment: The issue is: we intuitively know what is a point on the continuous line and we know that there are points on it to which **no** "usual" numbers correspond. Experiment: in the cartesian plan draw a circle with center the origin and radius the top right corner of the unit square. In what point the circumference will cross the $x$-axis? The issue was, for Cauchy, Dedenìkind, Cantor, etc, to "define" that point using **only** numbers: natural, rationals.

Comment: That machinery has not yet been introduced, and I so I don’t follow. It is clear how a partition in a cut defines a single real, but he jumps to the notion of a set of rationals left of that partition defining a real, there is a pedagogical leap here that I am not following.

Comment: Not looking for extended chat. Any other answers out there? Or is anyone getting what is confusing me?

Comment: Finally got it!